# mathjax doesn't work for me in comments

Tags: support, mathjax, comment

I'm getting good results using MathJax in answers, but it doesn't seem to work for me in comments.  I am in firefox 22.0 and OS is Ubuntu. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Two suggestions: 1) before posting a comment, preview it in the answer window **and** 2) in comments put empty spaces wherever possible in your formulas, especially in long expressions.